# How to deploy WAR using Netbeans 7.3.1 + JBoss AS7

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jboss, jboss7.x

This is an existing project that builds and deploys just fine using Intellij + AS7.  I want to build and deploy using Netbeans 7.3.1 so I created a new Maven project in NetBeans, selecting the "import the project using the Maven pom.xml files" option.  NetBeans recognized the modules and used Maven to build the project successfully.  Very nice.

```
Webapp assembled in [931 msecs]
Building war: G:\Patrac_Netbeans\Patrac-web\target\Patrac-web-1.0.war
```

Next, I started JBoss using NetBeans' Services panel.  Next, I clicked the Run Project button, expecting deployment to occur, but NetBeans only rebuilt the project again.  And then I remembered configuring Intellij to build & deploy using the target directory.  I don't see a way to do this in NetBeans.  So, how to set up the deployment using NetBeans?

**UPDATE 8/20/2013:**

The deployment of the EJB- and WAR modules work.  Here's the output when deploying the EJB:

> cd G:\Patrac_Netbeans\Patrac-ejb; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25" "\"G:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3.1\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat\"" -Dnetbeans.deploy=true package
>
> Scanning for projects...
>
> Building Patrac EJB module 1.0
>
> ...
>
> BUILD SUCCESS
>
> Total time: 8.251s
>
> Finished at: Tue Aug 20 14:33:38 EDT 2013
>
> Final Memory: 22M/364M
>
> NetBeans: Deploying on JBoss Application Server
>
> ```
> profile mode: false
> debug mode: false
> force redeploy: true
> ```
>
> Distributing G:\Patrac_Netbeans\Patrac-ejb\target\Patrac-ejb.jar to [org.jboss.as.ee.deployment.spi.DeploymentManagerTarget@45fbf23c]
>
> Deploying G:\Patrac_Netbeans\Patrac-ejb\target\Patrac-ejb.jar

However when I attempt to run the whole application NetBeans doesn't deploy:

> cd G:\Patrac_Netbeans; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25" "\"G:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3.1\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat\"" -Dnetbeans.deploy=true package
>
> Scanning for projects...
>
> Reactor Build Order:
>
> PATRAC
>
> Patrac EJB module
>
> Patrac Web module
>
> Building PATRAC 1.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> ...
>
> Building Patrac EJB module 1.0
>
> ...
>
> Building Patrac Web module 1.0
>
> ...
>
> [war:war]
>
> Packaging webapp
>
> Assembling webapp [Patrac-web] in [G:\Patrac_Netbeans\Patrac-web\target\Patrac.war]
>
> Processing war project
>
> Copying webapp resources [G:\Patrac_Netbeans\Patrac-web\src\main\webapp]
>
> Webapp assembled in [557 msecs]
>
> Building war: G:\Patrac_Netbeans\Patrac-web\target\Patrac-web-1.0.war
>
> Reactor Summary:
>
> PATRAC - Physician Assistant Tracking ............. SUCCESS [0.043s]
>
> Patrac EJB module ................................. SUCCESS [8.100s]
>
> Patrac Web module ................................. SUCCESS [2.324s]
>
> BUILD SUCCESS
>
> Total time: 10.882s
>
> Finished at: Tue Aug 20 14:17:34 EDT 2013
>
> Final Memory: 25M/366M

Why in the world does NetBeans not deploy?  Perhaps the problem is that it doesn't know where the assembled WAR is located?  Looking at the output, it runs Maven from `G:\Patrac_Netbeans`, which is where the root POM is located.  However the assembled WAR is located in `G:\Patrac_Netbeans\Patrac-web\target\Patrac.war`.

**UPDATE 8/21/2013:**

Fyi the plugin config was as follows:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.Final</version>
            </plugin>
```

As @happymeal correctly pointed out (see his comment, below), by simply looking at Maven's output the plugin was not running.  Thanks to @James R. Perkins I realized there were actually two plugins: `jboss-maven-plugin` and `jboss-as-maven-plugin` and because I was using the latter plugin I was using the wrong goal: `jboss:deploy` instead of `jboss-as:deploy`.  Correcting this mistake and rerunning the project in Netbeans the following error occurred:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\Patrac_Netbeans\target\Patrac-1.0-SNAPSHOT.maven-project (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Next, I added some configuration parameters that ultimately solved the problem:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <targetDir>G:\Patrac_Netbeans\Patrac-web\target</targetDir>
                    <filename>Patrac-web-1.0.war</filename>
                </configuration>                    
            </plugin>
```

Problem solved!

Comment: from your netbeans output, you are still running mvn.bat with the `package` goal: cd G:\Patrac_Netbeans; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25" "\"G:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3.1\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat\"" -Dnetbeans.deploy=true **package**. thus, your project is only built but not deployed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the default maven goal for the "Run Project" button in netbeans is `package`. this goal builds the project but does not deploy your app.

you can change this by:

1. right-clicking on your project and go to properties.
2. under the categories panel, select actions.
3. select the "Run Project" action and edit the "Execute Goals" textbox (e.g. `jboss:start`).

note that you will need the [jboss maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/).

Comment: The JBoss Maven plugin is installed and, after fiddling around with NetBeans, I noticed that both the EJB- and WAR deploy.  Weird.  `jboss:start` didn't help.  I've updated the question, above, in response to your helpful answer.

Comment: There is a jboss-as-maven-plugin that's made specifically for JBoss AS 7 and JBoss EAP as well. https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/

Comment: i have never used the jboss plugin before but i guess there is some configuration required. perhaps you might want to post your jboss maven plugin config from your POM.

Comment: Well as it turns out I had the jboss-as-maven-plugin installed, not the jboss-maven-plugin!  I did not realize that there were actually two plugins.  So, Maven was ignoring `jboss:deploy`.  After changing the goal to `jboss-as:deploy` the goal ran, with an error.  I've updated the question again to display the error.

Comment: Problem resolved by adding configuration parameters that eliminated the FileNotFoundException error.  Again, I've updated my question to reflect this.  Thanks y'all!